# Likelihood function sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $\mathbb{P} = \{p_{\theta}: \theta \in \Theta\}$ be a family of densities. Assume that the parameter space $\Theta$ is finite, that is $\Theta = \{\theta_0, \theta_1, \cdots, \theta_m\}$. Prove that the likelihood function, which is defined as $T(X) = (p_{\theta}(X))_{\theta \in \Theta}$ is sufficient but in general is not minimal sufficient.

Does the notation $T(\mathbf{X}) = (p_{\theta}(\mathbf{X}))_{\theta \in \Theta}$ just mean the likelihood function at a fixed $\theta$? Or does it mean a set of densities? I.e., $T(\mathbf{X}) = (p_{\theta}(\mathbf{X}))_{\theta \in \Theta} = (T_0(\mathbf{X}), \cdots, T_m(\mathbf{X})) = (p_{\theta_0}(\mathbf{X}), \cdots, p_{\theta_m}(\mathbf{X}))$?

How do I exactly prove this? Do I apply the factorization theorem? How do I show it is not minimal?